# Why Antlr4 could not resolve the declarator of FunctionDefinitionContext in C grammar

Tags: antlr4

Why Antlr4  in C grammar could not resolve the "declarator" of the "FunctionDefinitionContext" when we have a "declarationList" that includes only one parameter that is a pointer.

So if I parse the following function:

int print_queue(int idx,void * data)
parser retrieves  print_queue as the declarator

while when parsing :
int destroy_queue (void * data)

parser retrieves (void * data) as the declarator ( I think it considers it as a function pointer)

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Which grammar are you referring to? The C grammar from the grammars-v4 repository?

Comment: Yes the C grammar from the grammars-v4 repository

Comment: I think that grammar may simply be broken. It looks like the author may have tried to make typecasts work by treating identifiers as typenames as often as possible and broken some other cases in the process.

Comment: Relevant bug report: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/issues/1130

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in [the C grammar that you're using](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/fa26caafc18934fcc81e37d763cb1dac0dd808c2/c/C.g4). This bug has also been [reported on github](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/issues/1130).

The problem is that C's grammar has an ambiguity concerning typecasts. For example the expression `(a)(b)` matches both the rule for function calls (`(a)` would be a primary expression evaluating to a function pointer and `(b)` would be an argument list containing a single argument: the variable `b`) and the rule for casts (casting the value of the variable `b` to the type `a` (where `a` would be recognized as `typedef-name`)).

C resolves this ambiguity by saying that the `typedef-name` rule shall only be applied to identifiers that have actually been `typedef`ed. That is, the above example should be parsed as a typecast if and only if there's actually been a `typedef someType a;` previously in the file - otherwise it should be parsed as a function call. This is something that cannot be expressed in a context free grammar. For ANTLR this means that semantic predicates are needed to implement this rule.

However, that is not what the grammar in question does (maybe to keep the grammar language-agnostic or to keep it simple or maybe because the authors didn't know this was necessary to correctly parse all C code). Instead the original version resolved the ambiguity in favor of treating identifiers as variable names - simply due to the order of alternatives in the grammar. At some point someone noticed that this would not parse type casts correctly and "fixed" this by changing the order of the alternatives in the grammar. Now the ambiguity is resolved in favor of treating identifiers as type names. This fixes the type cast case, but breaks your example because now the `print_queue` in your code is interpreted as a type name.

> How to solve this issue?

You could revert to the version of the grammar before the commit that fixed typed casts. Then your code should work, but type casts to `typedef`ed types wouldn't work. If you want the grammar to produce the correct parse in all cases, you'll need to add actions and predicates to the grammar.

To do this, you'd add a set of `typedef`ed names to the parser, like this (the following code is in Java if you're using a different language, you'll have to adjust it accordingly):

```
@parser::header {
    import java.util.HashSet;
    import java.util.Set;
}

@parser::members {
    private Set<String> typedefs = new HashSet<String>();
}
```

Then you'd make the whole grammar distinguish between `typedef`ed identifiers and other identifiers by first renaming `Identifier` to something like `IdentifierOrTypedefName`, then adding an `identifier` rule and changing the `typedefName` rule as follows:

```
typedefName
    : {typedefs.contains(getCurrentToken().getText())}? IdentifierOrTypedefName
    ;

identifier
    : {!typedefs.contains(getCurrentToken().getText())}? IdentifierOrTypedefName
    ;
```

Now all the other places that previously referred to `Identifier` should instead refer to `identifier`. This way identifiers will only be seen as types if they're in the set of typedefs and only as variable or function names if they're not.

Now all that's left is to actually populate the set. For that we need to add an action to the `declaration` rule, that adds all declared identifiers to the set if the declaration is a `typedef`. We can do that like this:

```
declaration
    :   declarationSpecifiers initDeclaratorList ';' {
        if ($declarationSpecifiers.ctx.specifiers.stream().anyMatch(specifier -> specifier.getText().equals("typedef"))) {
            ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(new CBaseListener() {
                @Override
                public void exitIdentifier(IdentifierContext id) {
                    typedefs.add(id.getText());
                }
            }, $initDeclaratorList.ctx);
        }
    }
    |   declarationSpecifiers ';'
    |   staticAssertDeclaration
    ;

declarationSpecifiers
    :   specifiers+=declarationSpecifier+
    ;
```

With those changes the grammar should now work both with type casts (if the types used in the type cast have been properly `typedef`ed) and with your example.